How to get rollout percentage of a production android application via Google Play Console API's?
I'm creating a slack bot which can query google play console every 12hrs & get the rolled percentage of a specific production app. (For ex: If a production app is rolled out to 95% of users, this slack bot can fetch this from google play console API and share it with release engineering team)
I've skimmed through the play console api's document but found no API's which can help me with this GET Query. Is it even possible to get the existing rolled out percentage for an android app from google play console?
If possible, can you please help me with detailed documentation or sample app which does this?
